# How to find expected results from SQL queries

Tags: sql

I am currently writing a C++ application to parse and execute SQL statements. I have got so far with it but now I am finding it difficult to continue because I don't known what **should** happen in certain situations, for example with table joins, like in:

```
SELECT col1.table1, col2.table2 
FROM table1, table2;
```

with no explicit JOIN specified.

Is there a website or book or something I can refer to to find what's supposed to happen in particular circumstances? I have found one or two web sites that allow interactive SQL but they are more concerned with correct syntax etc.

I want to be able to find what should happen, even (especially) if it just means an appropriate error message.

Comment: Why not just use a program like SQL Server Management Studio. Create your tables and run your queries to see what happens.

Comment: If you cant create a local database for learning, maybe http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ should help you

Comment: @Duston, thanks for your reply. I have installed MySQL which looks like it may serve my purposes. If you make your comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify what type of SQL server you were working with, but MySQL is free, and some commercial SQL vendors have free developer versions of their products. Install it and try it out.

Answer (score 1):

That's old syntax for a `CROSS JOIN`. Essentially all rows from table 1 combined with all rows from table 2: the full cross product of both tables.

It's a perfectly valid SQL syntax, but just old (from the 80's and 90's). You better use/accept `CROSS JOIN` only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what *should* happen, then the SQL2016 standard is the only place to look: https://www.iso.org/standard/63555.html

> ISO/IEC 9075-1:2016 describes the conceptual framework used in other parts of ISO/IEC 9075 to specify the grammar of SQL **and the result of processing statements in that language by an SQL-implementation**.

It's ~$175...